# Was Big Bang a phase transition?

Tags: phase-transition, big-bang, critical-phenomena

Was Big Bang a phase transition (critical phenomenon)? If "yes", what is the order parameter and what determined the value of the order parameter chosen?

When talking about phase transitions we usually assume existence of fluctuations that affect the choice of the order parameters, but what could  have determined the direction of evolution of the Universe as a whole?

**Background**
Wikipedia article on Big Bang mentions phase transition in two instances:

> At approximately $10^{−37}$ seconds into the expansion, a ***phase transition*** caused a cosmic inflation, during which the universe grew exponentially, unconstrained by the light speed invariance, and temperatures dropped by a factor of 100,000.

and

> ***Symmetry-breaking phase transitions*** put the fundamental forces of physics and the parameters of elementary particles into their present form, with the electromagnetic force and weak nuclear force separating at about $10^{−12}$ seconds.

(Emphasis is mine)

**See also:** [Phase transitions in the early universe](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.09136) by Hindmarsh et al.

Comment: What observation do you propose to answer this question?

Comment: @JohnDoty I am asking about the theoretical description/understanding. Anderson seems to refer to it in [*More is Different*](https://www.tkm.kit.edu/downloads/TKM1_2011_more_is_different_PWA.pdf), but I do not have relevant background to understand what he is talking about.

Comment: @RogerVadim the reference to Anderson is interesting: where exactly? For sure, as the Universe was expanding, some phase transitions (related to spontaneous symmetry breaking) occurred, maybe Anderson was referring to this.

Comment: By "Big Bang" do you mean the point at which inflation stopped and the expansion phase we see today started? If so are you asking about the transition from inflation to non-inflation?

Comment: @JohnRennie perhaps, I have little background on the subject. What really interests me here is whether/how we can talk about phase transition in a system not subject to external influences. And also - a system with truly infinite number of particles (rather than a thermodynamic limit.)

Comment: @Quillo you are right, Anderson speaks of *symmetry breaking* in particle physics, but not really about big bang.

Comment: These phase transitions occurred *after* the Big Bang.

Comment: @Ghoster or *during* perhaps? Anyhow, the questions that I raise do not depend on that - the transitions happened in the whole universe - infinite,and without any external fluctuations.

Comment: Whether the universe is infinite is not a settled issue. The data seem to indicate that it is on the borderline between open and closed. The simplest assumption consistent with the data is that it is spatially flat and therefore infinite in extent, but we can’t be sure of this.

Comment: *What could have determined the direction of evolution of the Universe as a whole?* The fact that it is expanding and cooling. Why is it puzzling that a cooling universe has phase transitions?

Comment: @Ghoster *infinite* here refers to the number of particles. Phase transition is a choice between several equivalent possibilities - why would Universe choose one and not another?

Comment: Our discussion has become too long.